# Corona: Touch Eventlistener on newWebView

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to add an Touch Eventlistener to a webview?

```
  touchedwebview = function()
    print ("----- webview is touched !!!")
  end
  webview:addEventListener("touch",touchedwebview)
```

seems it does not work for me; I never get any response.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work. Because native web views are not part of the OpenGL canvas, they do not obey the Corona display object hierarchy.